# Dailymotion API Usage

Tags: dailymotion-api

I am just hitting below mentioned url of Dailymotion api to search for a video and then use video id to be played in videoplayer provided by daily motion.

https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?fields=description,id,taken_time,thumbnail_180_url,title,url,views_total,&search=kohli&limit=100

I am hitting this without any API key. Is there any limit for only this kind of usage?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit defined anywhere in Dailymotion API Documentation. API key is required for special requests like to generate access token, to get user information after logging in, to upload videos, mostly for authentications etc.

Comment: I confirm there is no limit yet on this kind of public call in Dailymotion API